# wpf radgridview How to get vertical offset of GridViewRow?

Tags: wpf, telerik, radgridview

I have row index of target GridViewRow, and ScrollChanged handler callback of GridViewScrollViewer inside RadGridView. I want to get vertical offset of target row in viewport, while scrolling, if that row leaves viewport from top, return 0; if leaves from bottom, return ActualHeight of RadGridView; else, get a value same as Top offest of target row and viewport.

Here is function to get vertival offset, it will be incorrect after scrollbar moved:

```
    //const int indicator_size = 3;
    //RadGridView grid;
    Func rowIndicatorOffset = (rowIndex) =>
    {
        double offset = (rowIndex + 1.5) * this.grid.RowHeight;
        if (offset > this.grid.ActualHeight)
        {
            return this.grid.ActualHeight - indicator_size;
        }
        return offset;
    };
```

[image: effects on UI]

When change vertical scroll bar offset, I want that indicator(red one in the picture above) keep same Y position with target row:

```
    //System.Windows.Controls.ScrollChangedEventArgs offsetValues (from ScrollChanged event)
    double fixRatio = (this.grid.ActualHeight - this.offsetValues.VerticalOffset) / this.grid.ActualHeight;
    double offset = (rowIndex + 1.5) * this.grid.RowHeight * fixRatio;
```

the code above works not well as expected apparently, so what's the answer?

[image: expected effect]

Answer (score 1):

I got it wrong about Viewport,  the diagram below may figure it out.

[diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfO8e.png)

```
    //const int indicator_size = 3;
    //RadGridView grid;
    Func<int, double> rowIndicatorOffset = (rowIndex) =>
    {                   
        double targetOffset = (rowIndex + 1.5) * this.grid.RowHeight;
        double viewportOffset = this.offsetValues.VerticalOffset;
        double offset = targetOffset - viewportOffset;
        if (offset > this.grid.ActualHeight)
        {
            return this.grid.ActualHeight - indicator_size;
        }
        else if (offset < 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            return offset;
        }
     };
```